# datatype mismatch with auto number when trying to check with msaccess

Tags: c#, asp.net

i am trying to run this code:

```
var _Session_ID = Session["USER_ID"];
Session_ID = Convert.ToInt32(Session_ID);
cmd = new OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM users WHERE [id] = '" + Session_ID + "'", conn);
```

but when ever i do it, it says Datatype mismatch 
my field `id` is a `autonumber` in ms access

Comment: Are you getting error while command execution? I think that's not the cause if the issue. Why do you get session value in `Session_ID` variable and try to convert it to integer and assign it to itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
cmd = new OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM users WHERE [id] = " + Session_ID, conn);
```

should fix it.

Don't enclose the values of numeric fields in quotes - Access will treat them as strings, and you can't compare a string to a number.

Comment: @Craftx398 Thanks. It should be noted that this issue would not have arisen if you used _parameterised queries_. It's also a _very_ good idea to adopt these to help prevent SQL Injection attacks. See http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/CSharp/0560__ADO.Net/ExecutingaParameterizedQuerywithOleDbCommand.htm for an example of building an OleDbCommand using parameters, instead of just joining strings together.